# Android library for WSS (Secure Web Socket)

Tags: android, https, websocket, wss

Im trying to connect to 
WSS (client+server certificate authentication + Corporate Proxy Authentication+Self Signed Certificate Chain) from Android.

I tried Autobhan library, Koush AsyncIO, SecureWebSocket, Autobahn library with TLS support And few other.

I could not get it working.

Any suggestions on support library or least possible alterations to my server configuration to make it work (Https mandatory) ?

Comment: Our SecureBlackbox should do the job. Your question is offtopic according to current SO rules.

Comment: @Eugene, My question is genuine question after my trails and I'm not asking any opinions or something. As per my knowledge it's valid. How am I going off topic here?

Comment: The questions to recommend a library or a tool are off-topic now. It's just a note, I am not a moderator.

Comment: That's a silly thing to be 'off topic' often times one cannot discern by Google alone what the best library for a task might be.  It is useful to get input from people who have used it and SO has always been a great forum for such opinions.

Comment: I love off topic questions, they usually have the answers I need, even if the so-called 'experts' don't think I need them.

Comment: 1000+ views. Still no valid Answer?

Comment: In this case it is not off topic IMHO. The writer is saying that no library works and it needs to know one that works.

Comment: this is ws/wss socket from firebase https://github.com/firebase/TubeSock

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket

I haven't used it myself, but it looks promising.

Comment: @mgiammarco actually it works with ssl https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/issues/141

Comment: this library always fails with handshake, i have been stuck with it for 2 days now and still no fixes found yet

Answer (score 3):

Just recently discovered this [library (nv-websocket-client)](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client). The best websocket client library for Android and Java so far. It supports WSS and RFC 7692.

Comment: There is a problem with that library. It does not detect when the server side connection goes down in order to call the onDisconnected method on the client

Answer (score 1):

I am using Tyrus library.
It works but only on Android 4.
On Android 5 it hits a bug in Android. The bug happens only on ssl connections.

Comment: You can find a list of WebSocket libraries for Android here: [Which WebSocket library to use in Android app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547517/which-websocket-library-to-use-in-android-app)